# Передать данные из Activity во фрагменты

Tags: android

Есть MainActivity и два фрагмента, которые находятся в PlayerActivity (т.е. PlayerActivity состоит из двух фрагментов). В основной (MainActivity) в RecyclerView выводится список из БД. Как мне при нажатии на элемент списка передать в оба фрагмента id записи? Сейчас в методе onItemClick id записи передается в PlayerActivity, который не содержит фрагментов, но я переделал активность с плеером и сейчас нужно передать в оба фрагмента id, чтобы в одном фрагменте вывести данные о записи такие как название песни, сам плеер и т.д., а во второй активности текст песни

Вот сейчас у меня все устроено так.. Специально создал новый проект чтобы понять как передать данные во фрагменты

Fragment1

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {

    public static final String ARG1 = "arg1";

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container,false);

        Bundle args = getArguments();

        TextView txtOne = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.txtOne);
        txtOne.setText(args.getString(ARG1));

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Fragment2

```
public class Fragment2 extends Fragment {

    public static final String ARG2 = "arg2";

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment2, container,false);

        Bundle args = getArguments();

        TextView txtTwo = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.txtTwo);
        txtTwo.setText(args.getString(ARG2));

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

MyPagerAdapter

```
public class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        Fragment fragment1 = new Fragment1();
        Fragment fragment2 = new Fragment2();

        Bundle args = new Bundle();

        if (i == 0) {
            args.putString(Fragment1.ARG1, "Это первый фрагмент");
            fragment1.setArguments(args);
            return fragment1;
        } else {
            args.putString(Fragment2.ARG2, "Это второй фрагмент");
            fragment2.setArguments(args);
            return fragment2;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 2;
    }

}
```

Метод из MainActivity, который отправляет id записи в PlayerActivity

```
@Override
    public void onItemClick(int pos) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, PlayerActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("id", pos);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Если пытаюсь из PlayerActivity или MainActivity передать id таким образом и удалить передачу аргументов во фрагменты в классе MyPagerAdapter

```
Bundle args = new Bundle();

        args.putLong(Fragment1.ARG1, id);

        Fragment1 f1 = new Fragment1();

        f1.setArguments(args);
```

то выдает ошибку

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'java.lang.String android.os.Bundle.getString(java.lang.String)' on a
>   null object reference at
>   ru.test.viewpager.Fragment1.onCreateView(Fragment1.java:23) at
>   android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2354)
>   at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1419)
>   at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1740)
>   at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1809)
>   at
>   android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:799)
>   at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2580)
>   at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2367)
>   at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2322)
>   at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:2199)
>   at
>   android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:651)
>   at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:145) at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1236) at
>   android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1084) at
>   android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1614) at
>   android.view.View.measure(View.java:21125) at
>   android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:715)
>   at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461) at
>   android.view.View.measure(View.java:21125) at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6461) at
>   android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185) at
>   android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:139)
>   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:21125) at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6461) at
>   android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:400)
>   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:21125) at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6461) at
>   android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185) at
>   android.view.View.measure(View.java:21125) at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6461) at
>   android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
>   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:758)
>   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:640) at
>   android.view.View.measure(View.java:21125) at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6461) at
>   android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185) at
>   com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:896) at
>   android.view.View.measure(View.java:21125) at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2612) at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1664) at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1915) at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1537) at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7183)
>   at
>   android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:959)
>   at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:734) at
>   android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:670) at
>   android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:945)
>   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1518)
>   01-15 22:44:12.598 7458-7458/ru.test.viewpager E/AndroidRuntime:
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1408)

На строке `txtOne.setText(args.getString(ARG1));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте следующее:

PlayerActivity:

```
public class PlayerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private MyPagerAdapter adapter;
private ViewPager viewPager;
private TabLayout tabLayout;
private String id = "";

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_player);

    viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);

    id = getIntent().getStringExtra("id");

    setupViewPager();
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
}

private void setupViewPager() {
    adapter = new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(Fragment1.newInstance(id),"Первый фрагмент");
    adapter.addFragment(Fragment2.newInstance(id),"Второй фрагмент");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}}
```

activity_player.xml:

```
<FrameLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="8dp">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
        style="@style/TabLayoutStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="32dp"/>

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

MyPagerAdapter:

```
public class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

private List<Fragment> fragments = new ArrayList<>();
private List<String> titles = new ArrayList<>();

public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return fragments.get(position);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return fragments.size();
}

@Nullable
@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return titles.get(position);
}

void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
    fragments.add(fragment);
    titles.add(title);
}}
```

Ваш фрагмент:

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {

public static Fragment1 newInstance(String id) {
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("ID", id);

    Fragment1 fragment1 = new Fragment1();
    fragment1.setArguments(args);
    return fragment1;
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    String id = getArguments().getString("ID");
    //И далее доставайте из базы нужную информацию по ID
}}
```

Второй фрагмент по аналогии с первым.

Comment: А зачем TabLayout? Я не хочу вкладки

Comment: Тогда просто без него, и title повыпиливать отовсюду, я на автомате уже пишу.

Comment: Просмотрел ваш ответ.. сейчас попробую без Title сделать по вашему ответу

Comment: пример рабочий, делал на Kotlin неделю назад, мог ошибиться в переводе на Java, ну да среда подскажет, я думаю, где надо. И вьюпейджер у меня был во фрагменте, а не в активити, но там отличие только в передаче в адаптер childFragmentManager, здесь у Вас обычный supportFragmentManager

Comment: А как в классе Fragment1 в методе onCreateView записать в переменную данные которые передали во фрагмент? Я пока что хочу в TextView из fragment1.xml вывести значение id которое передаем во фрагмент?  Вот так TextView txtOne = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.txtOne); я получил сам TextView

Comment: Делайте это в методе onViewCreated() - это абсолютно нормально. Метод на вход принимает view, которую вы инфлейтили, так что все аналогично view.findViewById(...)

Comment: Делаю по вашему ответу почему-то во фрагмент приходит null

Comment: Ну это уже похоже моя ошибка и не связана с передачей аргументов. Спасибо, буду разбираться

Comment: залогируйте айдишник который достаете уже в PlayerActivity, если он не null то тогда странно почему во фрагменты уходит null

Comment: Уже смотрел, каждый раз id почему-то равен 0, разбираюсь почему

Comment: Разобрался, спасибо большое все получилось.

Comment: @Kolhoznik отлично

Comment: А у меня возник для себя такой вопрос. В моем случае, мне нужно было в оба фрагмента передать один и тот же аргумент. А как быть если в первый фрагмент нужно передать 2 параметра, а во второй фрагмент например 4 параметра? Нужно для каждого фрагмента создать отдельный метод setupViewPager и передавать в него необходимое число параметров или?

Comment: параметры передаем в статический метод фрагмента newInstance(String id), у каждого фрагмента он свой, передавайте сколько угодно разных парметров в каждый (в разумных пределах). А я понял о чем вы, можно было бы String id не делать локальной переменной в методе onCreate() у PlayerActivity и вынести как поле класса и напрямую ее дергать из метода setupViewPager() ничего не передавая ему в качестве аргумента, также можно объявить и кучу других полей.

Comment: А что за аргумент id в методе setupViewPager?

Comment: отредактировал ответ

Comment: Спасибо. Меня id в методе setupViewPager смутил и не мог понять для чего он, если при создании фрагмента передаются нужные данные. Сейчас понятно.

Comment: Просто переменная String id была объявлена локально в методе onCreate() и область ее видимости ограничивалась методом onCreate(), то есть напрямую внутри метода setupViewPager() мы бы ее не достали/не могли передать в Fragment1.newInstance(id)

Comment: Понял. Спасибо.